# multiply two dataframes by matching rows and columns

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I would like to multiply two data frames or matrices by matching the rows in Df1 with column names in DF2.
The data frames look like

```
Df1<- 
| ID   |Value|
|:---- |:----|
| 105  |213|
| 105  |214|
| 90  |215|
| 90  |216|
| 100  |217|

Df2<- 
| 90 | 100 | 105 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 10 | 11    | 12 |
| 15  | 20    | 25 |
| 20  | 25    | 30 |
```

My goal is to match the 'ID' in Df1 with the colnames in Df2 and multiply the Value in Df1 with the matched columns in the Df2. The output should look like:

output<-

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 213*12 | 214*12 | 215*10 |
| 213*25 | 214*25 | 215*15 |
| 213*30 | 214*30 | 215*20 |

What would be the fastest and convenient method to do this. I am relatively new to the R and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this question relate to python or pandas?

Comment: @JonSpring I am trying to do this is R but any python solution is also appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

We can try

```
with(
  df1,
  as.data.frame(t(t(unname(df2[as.character(ID)])) * Value))
)
```

which gives

```
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
1 2556 2568 2150 2160 2387
2 5325 5350 3225 3240 4340
3 6390 6420 4300 4320 5425
```

---

Maybe this base R code with `reshape` + `merge` could help

```
reshape(
  transform(
    type.convert(
      merge(df1, stack(df2), by.x = "ID", by.y = "ind", all = TRUE),
      as.is = TRUE
    ),
    idx = ave(ID, ID, Value, FUN = seq_along),
    p = Value * values
  )[c("Value", "idx", "p")],
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "idx",
  timevar = "Value"
)
```

which gives

```
  idx p.215 p.216 p.217 p.213 p.214
1   1  3225  3240  5425  6390  6420
2   2  2150  2160  2387  2556  2568
3   3  4300  4320  4340  5325  5350
```

---

## Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(105, 105, 90, 90, 100),
  Value = 213:217
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  `90` = c(10, 15, 20),
  `100` = c(11, 20, 25),
  `105` = c(12, 25, 30),
  check.names = FALSE
)
```

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding Thanks for your solution. The code works but the rows and columns in output are randomly generated. My actual data frames are quite large and I need an ordered output data frame as specified in the question. Any suggestion on how can it be achieved?

Comment: @JunaidAhmad See my update